# "a.getFullYear is not a function" when trying to get date difference

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get a date difference between a date and today with JS.
Here is my code, but I get "a.getFullYear is not a function".

```
var brbr = '<br><br>';
var duedate="2015-11-06";
document.write(duedate);
document.write(brbr);

// Today's date:
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.write(today);
document.write(brbr);

// DIFFERENCE 2 dates:
var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;


// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    // Discard the time and time-zone information.
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

Result:

```
var days_left = dateDiffInDays(today, duedate);
document.write(days_left);
document.write(brbr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `today` and `duedate` into `Date()` objects in order to use `.getFullYear()`

```
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var aDate = new Date(a);
    var bDate = new Date(b);

    // Discard the time and time-zone information.
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(aDate.getFullYear(), aDate.getMonth(), aDate.getDate());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(bDate.getFullYear(), bDate.getMonth(), bDate.getDate());
    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry to mark correct many years later. I edited the answer a little bit. And your upvote on my question is much appreciated! : )

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

```
var a = Date.parse("date");
var b = new Date(a);
```

Comment: replace "date" with your date variable or string, in my case it was a string.